# How to get the expression $\frac{\sinh(\beta mx)}{\cosh(\beta mt)}$ in solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose, we assume that the function $v(x,t)$ has the form
$$
v(x,t)=4\arctan\left[\frac{\phi(x)}{\psi(t)}\right]\tag{1}
$$
and are given the differential equations
$$
\phi_x=-k^2\phi^3+m\phi+n^2,\qquad\psi_t=k^2\psi^3+\sqrt{m^2-1}\psi-n^2,\tag{2}
$$
where $k,m,n$ are constants.

Assume that $k=0$ and $m>1$. Do we then get
$$
v(x,t)=4\arctan\left[\frac{\beta\sinh(\beta mx)}{\cosh(\beta mt)}\right],\tag{3}
$$
where $\beta=\frac{\sqrt{m^2-1}}{m}$?

(See [equations (25)-(26) and (33)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sine-GordonEquation.html) for this problem.)

---

If $k=0$ and $m>1$, then the equations (2) read
$$
\phi_x=m\phi+n^2,\qquad\psi_t=\sqrt{m^2-1}\psi-n^2
$$
which yields
$$
\phi(x)=\frac{1}{m}(e^{mx}-n^2),\qquad \psi(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m^2-1}}(e^{\sqrt{m^2-1}t}+n^2).
$$

Plugging this into (1),
$$
v(x,t)=4\arctan\left[\frac{\sqrt{m^2-1}(e^{mx}-n^2)}{m(e^{\sqrt{m^2-1}t}+n^2)}\right]=4\arctan\left[\beta\frac{e^{mx}-n^2}{e^{\beta m t}+n^2}\right].
$$

Is it possible to continue from here in order to get (3)? I do not see that
$$
\frac{e^{mx}-n^2}{e^{\beta m t}+n^2}=\frac{\sinh(\beta mx)}{\cosh(\beta m t)}
$$
and my feeling is that it is simply not true.

**Edit**:

In the given link, one reference is a book by Infeld and Rowland. There, instead of (3), the solution is given as
$$
v(x,t)=4\arctan\left[\frac{\beta\sinh(mx)}{\cosh(\beta mt)}\right]\tag{3'},
$$
that is, without the $\beta$ appearing in the argument of $\sinh$. Does that help? Suppose (3') is the correct form of the solution. Then I still have the problem to see
$$
\frac{e^{mx}-n^2}{e^{\beta m t}+n^2}=\frac{\sinh(mx)}{\cosh(\beta m t)}.
$$

Comment: Two things: (1) I believe you need to take a specific value of $n$ ($n=1$ starts getting you closer to that form, particularly); (2) there's likely an additional ansatz needed to get the specific solution in (33) . Have you read the linked source material?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki As to (1): That's possible! (2) I tried to look in the mentioned reference (Infeld, E. and Rowlands, G. Nonlinear Waves, Solitons, and Chaos, 2nd ed. Cambridge, England: Cambridge University Press, 2000.); unfortunately, I do not have access.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki In the book, the form of the solution is slightly different. I added this as an edit.